# Incorrect indexPath inside tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a table view with 14 cells. One of that cells has dynamic height.

So, I'm setting this height inside tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
print(indexPath.row)
    if calculatedHeight != nil && indexPath.row == 10 {
        return calculatedHeight!
    }

    return commonCellHeight
}
```

I was expecting to get printed output like this:

```
0
1
2
...
13
```

This should be printed two or more times. That's not the matter.

But instead I'm getting:

```
0
0
1
2
...
12
0
1
2
...
13
```

Sometimes it counts from 0 to 13 as expected and sometimes from 0 to 12 with two zeros in the beginning.

Because of this, I'm setting the height for the wrong cell.
When I check for `if calculatedHeight != nil && indexPath.row == 10`, I'm actually setting the height for the 12th row, but not for the 11th as desired.

What's happening? Where is my mistake?

---

**UPDATE**

So, I've managed to solve the problem.

The point was that I've called `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` before the table was doing it's internal stuff. Even before the first call to `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`.

Now, when I've removed early selection, things are going right and indexPath.row == 10 corresponds to 11th row as expected.

---

**NOTICE**

I don't consider this to be a good answer for question because I don't really understand why it is happening in such manner.

So, if you know the real reason, please post your answer and I'll probably accept it.

Comment: Tableview datasource methods can be called in any order, but indexPath.row==10 will always be for the 11th row

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, I was expecting that logic. But it is not. In fact I'm setting the 12th row height. I can see it when I'm launching the app.

Comment: @Paulw11, also this is the methd of the tableview's delegate but not the datasource.

Comment: can you show your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method?

Comment: @Binesh, I'm not overriding it. It is the tableview with static cells.

Comment: Where are you calling your `NSLog` to print the `indexPath.row`? Can you check how many times your `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called?

Comment: @Rikh, I'm calling Swift's ``print``. It is at the first line of ``tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)``. Numberofrows is called twice.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad! I brain lagged for a second.